# How to show the full name of an object in powerpoint 2013 animation pane

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have a powerpoint 2013 slide with tens of objects that I want to animate. I have used the selection pane to give each of the objects a meaningful name to make it easier to order them properly. But I don't seem to be able to show more than the first few letters in the custom animation pane and this makes the naming pretty useless. The column for the animation name seems to stuck to a very narrow width.

**Is there a way of making the object name column of the animation pane wider to show the full name of the object?**

Comment: Wow, you're right.  Boneheaded UI design!  While you can expand the animation pane, PPT doesn't use the extra space for names.  It just leaves it blank and limits the shape names to 12 or 13 characters. You can leave the Selection pane and the Animation pane both visible; the selection pane will show you the full names of the shapes if it's wide enough.

Answer (score 1):

While you won't be able to see the full object name in the animation pane, you can go to the "Selection Pane" which, to my experience, does not have the same number of limitations. As described [on this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074209/how-to-name-an-object-within-a-powerpoint-slide), you need to first select an object in order to make the "Drawing Tools" (Format pane) available. In the "Arrange" section, there's a small button called "Selection Pane".